# php data from text file to multidimensional array doesnt work but no console errors

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've written some code to read in data from a text file.
The data looks like this:

11:12:12:test titel 1
12:13:13:test titel 2
13:14:14:test titel 3

the following code reads the date, splits it one string for each line, those go in one array. This works perfectly. 
After this, it should devide each line again in string that go in an array, and all these arrays go into one multidimensional array. 
This last part doesnt work...
I think it's strange that instead of errors, of half the page, it shows just an empty page...
also, I've tried putting some of the code in comment, and so I've narrowed it down a bit. I give you guys the commented code, but all the comments should go away, and it should work like that! 
thanks!

```html
 <?php
$filename = "data.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
$content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
$parts = null;
fclose($fp);
print_r($lines);
echo sizeof($lines);
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($lines)-1 ; $i++) {    //the minus 1 corrects the empty line automatically added when saving the data.txt file
  //$tempParts[] = explode(":", $lines[i]);
  //array_push($parts, $tempParts);
}
//echo "<br/>"
echo "all parts: "
//for ($row=0; $row < sizeof($lines)-1; $row++) {
//  for ($col=0; $col < sizeof($parts[$row]); $col++) {
//echo $parts[$row][$col];
//  }
//}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think preg_split will do what you want.

```
$filename = "data.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r");
$content = fread($fp, filesize($filename));

//$content = "11:12:12:test titel 1
            12:13:13:test titel 2
            13:14:14:test titel 3";

$arr = preg_split("/(:|\n)/" ,$content);


var_dump($arr);
```

See here: http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hNH
Click on preg_split on the right side of the screen to make it work

Maybe this works better for you?

```
preg_match_all("/(\d+):(\d+):(\d+):(.*)/", $content, $arr);
```

Click preg_match_all:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hNW

Comment: This way i get a single dimensional array, but it should work like this! thanks! Nice website btw!

Comment: @pieter-jangoeman I updated my answer with preg_match_all instead.

Comment: hmm, how is this better?

Comment: @pieter-jangoeman depends on how you plan to use the data. With preg_match you get each column as a new array. That means if you want to only echo the titles you can loop an echo in array[4]. But as I said. It all depends on how you use the data

Comment: @pieter-jangoeman no problem! If it solved your problem it would be nice if you accepted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want but you can try this :

```
if (!$fp = fopen("data.txt","r")) {
    die("fail to open");
}else {
    $all = array();
    $row = 1;
    while(!feof($fp)) { // foreach line
        $ligne = fgets($fp,255); // get line content
        $cols = explode(':', $line); // gets cols
        $all[$row++] = $cols; // put cols on current row 
    }    
    var_dump($all); // dump all data stored by row
    fclose($fp);
}
```